# Search and display entries in SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I recently got into Android programming and have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t8VVWebRFM) tutorial on how to insert, update, delete and view data in an SQLite database. Now, I would also like to add a search functionality to this SQLite database where I can search for a name (the columns I'm using are name, contact and DOB) and if the searched for name matches an existing one in the database, display this row/entry from the database in the application. I figured this could be done in a similar way as the viewing/updating the database, so I tried coming up with a solution for this with these as reference, however after having tried a good amount of ways that seemed reasonable to me I still haven't gotten it to work, so I'd greatly appreciate any help with this! I feel like I was close w/ some of my attempts but something with the logic didn't click completely.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



EditText name, contact, dob;
Button insert, update, delete, view, search;
DBHelper DB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);
    dob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
    insert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    update = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    delete = findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    view = findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    search = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    DB = new DBHelper(this);

   
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nameTXT = name.getText().toString();
            String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString();
            String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString();

            Boolean checkinsertdata = DB.insertuserdata(nameTXT, contactTXT, dobTXT);
            
            if(checkinsertdata==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }        });
    

    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nameTXT = name.getText().toString();
            String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString();
            String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString();

            Boolean checkupdatedata = DB.updateuserdata(nameTXT, contactTXT, dobTXT);
          
            if(checkupdatedata==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }        });

    
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nameTXT = name.getText().toString();
            Boolean checkudeletedata = DB.deletedata(nameTXT);
           
            if(checkudeletedata==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }        });

    
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Cursor res = DB.getdata();
            if(res.getCount()==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

          
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while(res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Contact :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Date of Birth :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
            }
            
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("User Entries");
            builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
            builder.show();
        }        });


  }

}
```

DBHelper.java:

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import ...

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, "Userdata.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {
    
    DB.execSQL("create Table Userdetails(name TEXT primary key," +
            "contact TEXT, dob TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    DB.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");
}


public Boolean insertuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {
    
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("contact", contact);
    contentValues.put("dob", dob);


    long result = DB.insert("Userdetails",
            null, contentValues);
    
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Boolean updateuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {
    
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("contact", contact);
    contentValues.put("dob", dob);
    
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery(
            "Select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});

    
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   

        long result = DB.update("Userdetails",
                contentValues, "name=?",
                new String[]{name});
        
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public Boolean deletedata(String name) {
    
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery(
            "Select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});

   
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       

        long result = DB.delete("Userdetails", "name=?",
                new String[]{name});
      
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


public Cursor getdata () {
    
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery(
            "Select * from Userdetails ", null);
    return cursor;

}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please enter details below"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:hint="Contact"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:inputType="number"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dob"
    android:hint="Date of Birth"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact"
    android:inputType="number"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnInsert"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="Insert New Data"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dob"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="Update Data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnInsert"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="Delete Data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnUpdate"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnView"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="View Data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDelete"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:text="Search Data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnView"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry in advance for perhaps some bad explanations/something not making sense, I'm only a few weeks into this and got a lot to learn for sure! Thanks

Comment: How you use your search button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `getdata()` so that it takes as an argument the name, or part of the name that you search for:

```
public Cursor getdata(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "Select * from Userdetails";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    if (name != null) {
        sql += " where name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'";
        selectionArgs = new String[] {name};
    }
    return DB.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
}
```

and you should also modify in the listener of the button `view` the call to `getdata()` to  pass `null` so that you get as result all the rows of the table:

```
Cursor res = DB.getdata(null);
```

Then you create the listener for the button `search`:

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String searchName = name.getText().toString().trim();
        if (searchName.length() == 0) return;

        Cursor res = DB.getdata(searchName);
        if(res.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(res.moveToNext()){
            buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Contact :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Date of Birth :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("User Entries");
        builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
        builder.show();
    }
});
```

Note that there is no need to query the table before you insert, update, delete a row.
You can perform the operation that you want and then examine the result of the method `insert()` or `update()` or `delete()` to decide whether it was successful or not.
Remember that only `insert()` returns `-1` if unsuccessful.
`update()` and `delete()` return the number of affected (updated/deleted) rows.

So, I would write the code like this:

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Userdata.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {
        DB.execSQL("create Table Userdetails(name TEXT primary key, contact TEXT, dob TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        DB.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");
    }

    public Boolean insertuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("contact", contact);
        contentValues.put("dob", dob);
        long result = DB.insert("Userdetails", null, contentValues);
        return (result != -1);
    }

    public Boolean updateuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("contact", contact);
        contentValues.put("dob", dob);
        long result = DB.update("Userdetails", contentValues, "name = ?", new String[]{name});
        return (result > 0);
    }

    public Boolean deletedata(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = DB.delete("Userdetails", "name = ?", new String[]{name});
        return (result > 0);
    }

    public Cursor getdata(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "Select * from Userdetails";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        if (name != null) {
            sql += " where name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'";
            selectionArgs = new String[] {name};
        }
        return DB.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    }
}
```

and for the activity class:

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, contact, dob;
    Button insert, update, delete, view, search;
    DBHelper DB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);
        dob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
        insert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        update = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        delete = findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        view = findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        search = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        DB = new DBHelper(this);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nameTXT = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString().trim();
                String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString().trim();

                Boolean checkinsertdata = DB.insertuserdata(nameTXT, contactTXT, dobTXT);

                if(checkinsertdata==true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nameTXT = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString().trim();
                String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString().trim();

                Boolean checkupdatedata = DB.updateuserdata(nameTXT, contactTXT, dobTXT);

                if(checkupdatedata==true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New Entry Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nameTXT = name.getText().toString().trim();
                Boolean checkudeletedata = DB.deletedata(nameTXT);

                if(checkudeletedata==true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Cursor res = DB.getdata(null);
                if(res.getCount()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while(res.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Contact :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Date of Birth :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("User Entries");
                builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
                builder.show();
            }
        });

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String searchName = name.getText().toString().trim();
                if (searchName.length() == 0) return;

                Cursor res = DB.getdata(searchName);
                if(res.getCount()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while(res.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Contact :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Date of Birth :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("User Entries");
                builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This made a lot of sense and helped me solve it, thank you! I was scratching the surface of a solution like this but now that I see how you solved it I obviously missed out on some important parts!

Answer (score 0):

In DBHelper.java add:

```
public Cursor getDataByName(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Userdetails WHERE name LIKE '%"+name+"'%", null);
}
```

In MainActivity.java:

Add a new global EditText:

```
EditText name, contact, dob, **search**;
```

onCreate() add:

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        searchInDatabase();
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your MainActivity.java add this new method.

```
private void searchInDatabaseByName(){
    Cursor res = DB.getDataByName(name.getText().toString());
    if(res.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Cursor res = DB.getdata();
    if(res.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Entry Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

  
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Contact :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Date of Birth :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
    }
    
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("User Entries");
    builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
    builder.show();
}
```

Now the explanation:

In sqlite you can query for data using the LIKE keyword. for example in order to find all the rows with the name 'Bob' you can query for

```
SELECT * FROM Userdetails WHERE name LIKE '%Bob%'
```

Then, the returned cursor will contain all the rows that have the name Bob.

Then we've added another EditText variable to search (you'll need to add it to the main_acitivity.xml as well).

Now you can use that to type in the name you want to search and then click the 'search' button, which in return will call the 'searchInDatabaseByName' method which does the exact same thing as your 'view' button but simply goes to our new DBHelper method 'getDataByName'.

Please notice that its recommended to let the DBHelper do all the stuff of fetching the actual data (meaning it will get the cursor and also parse it)

You might want to create a model class for your User entity.
and then the database method will return an arraylist of users which will later be much easier to show in a Dialog (or even better, in a ListView)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The reasoning and explanation makes sense to me however I didn't get it to work with the code, at first I got this error:

 EditText cannot be converted to String
        Cursor res = DB.getDataByName(name);

And when trying the suggested fix for this, Change 1st parameter of method 'getDataByName' from 'String' to 'EditText', the program didn't seem to display search results and when there where no matching results it ended up crashing. It is very possible that I messed something up on my end causing this, not sure what though.

Comment: Whoops, no its my bad lol. change name.getText().toString()